# Apache Pig: OutOfMemoryError with FOREACH aggregation

Tags: apache-pig, emr

I'm getting an OutOfMemoryError with running a FOREACH operation in Apache Pig.

```
16/06/24 15:14:17 INFO util.SpillableMemoryManager: first memory     
handler call- Usage threshold init = 164102144(160256K) used =
556137816(543103K) committed = 698875904(682496K) max =
698875904(682496K)

java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
-XX:OnOutOfMemoryError="kill -9 %p"
Executing /bin/sh -c "kill -9 4095"... Killed
```

My Pig script:

```
A = LOAD 'PageCountTest/' USING PigStorage(' ') AS (Project:chararray, 
Title:chararray, count:int , size:int); 

B = GROUP A BY (Project,Title); 

C = FOREACH B 
generate group, SUM(A.count) AS COUNT; D = ORDER C BY COUNT DESC;

STORE C INTO '/user/hadoop/wikistats';
```

Sample Data:

```
aa.b Main_Page 1 14335
aa.d India 1 4075
aa.d Main_Page 1 13190
aa.d Special:RecentChanges 1 200
aa.d Talk:Main_Page/ 1 14147
aa.d w/w/index.php 9 137502
aa Main_Page 6 9872
aa Special:Statistics 1 324
```

Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 0):

I do suspect that a memory issue arise when you order by as it is the most heavy weighted. The easiest way is to play with the heap size parameters while launching your pig job.

```
pig -Dmapred.child.java.opts=-Xms2096M yourjob.pig
```

Also you can declare heap size directly inside the script.

```
export PIG_HEAPSIZE=2096
```